# How to handle emailserver exceptions in django-allauth eg ConnectionRefusedError?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have implemented django-allauth ok in my django project .
However if there is an issue with connecting to the mail server i get an exception. How can I handle these kind of exceptions since all the views are provided by all allauth.
[image: Error]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG

Comment: @iklinac thanks. but the question is about how to handle the exception since all the views are provided by allauth. ie even if i set DEBUG=false . the exception is not handled correctly and get internal server error. i want to be able to handle the exception